# Using hex flag inside setiosflags function

Tags: c++, iomanip

```
int a=60;
cout<<setiosflags(ios::hex|ios::showbase|ios::uppercase);
cout<<a<<endl;
```

The above code is not working but if I use

```
cout<<hex
```

and then

```
cout<<setiosflags(ios::showbase|ios::uppercase)
```

then it is working

Why? and how i do know which one can be used inside setiosflags() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`resetiosflags`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags) before you call `setiosflags`.  The reason for this is that `setiosflags(ios::hex|ios::showbase|ios::uppercase)` just appends these flags into the stream as if calling `setf` and that gives conflicting flags in the stream.  Using

```
std::cout << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::dec)
          << std::setiosflags(std::ios::hex|std::ios::showbase|std::ios::uppercase)
          << a << endl;
```

will make it display `a` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

With the first version, you first have to clear `std::ios::dec`, otherwise it takes precedence:

```
std::cout << resetiosflags (std::ios::dec);
```

You can do this in one hit by calling `setf` with the appropriate mask, e.g.:

```
std.cout.setf (std:ios.hex, std.ios.basefield);
```

And as documented at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), `std::cout << hex` does this for you.